# Beginner code looking for improvements

Tags: c++

I'm very new to C++. The code below is something I made and functions just fine. However, it seems rather long and I feel like it could be reduced - perhaps to increase efficiency.

The purpose of this code is to translate any DNA sequence into its respective amino acid sequence. It includes a portion where the DNA sequence is verified by the user. Three ORFs are generated using the inputted sequence.

Although it is functional, I have some issues with my program.

One, I would like to make the size of the amino acid array (AA_string1, 2, and 3) as large as they need to be. No concrete memory allocation (so I don't have to change the code all the time) and no wasted memory. Could this be accomplished by pointer arrays?

Two, if the user inputs something that is not expected (like a 2 where you were supposed to enter a 1 or 0), my program encounters an "out_of_range" memory error. I believe I could fix this by adding an error message upon invalid input and returning to a line of code just prior to where the error occurred. I attempted using the "goto" command to do this, laying out various labels for where I'd like the code to reset. This doesn't seem to be working. I continue to encounter an out_of_range memory error upon invalid input.

If you guys have any suggestions on the issues I mentioned or the code itself, let me know in the comments below!

P.S. I put asterisks around the lines of code that I mentioned in my issues.

```
int main()
{
// Key for converting DNA sequence to amino acid sequence.
string codons[64] = { "UUU","UUC","UUA","UUG","UCU","UCC","UCA","UCG","UAU","UAC","UAA","UAG","UGU","UGC","UGA","UGG",
    "CUU","CUC","CUA","CUG","CCU","CCC","CCA","CCG","CAU","CAC","CAA","CAG","CGU","CGC","CGA","CGG",
    "AUU","AUC","AUA","AUG","ACU","ACC","ACA","ACG","AAU","AAC","AAA","AAG","AGU","AGC","AGA","AGG",
    "GUU","GUC","GUA","GUG","GCU","GCC","GCA","GCG","GAU","GAC","GAA","GAG","GGU","GGC","GGA","GGG" };
string aminoAcids[64] = { "Phe(F)","Phe(F)","Leu(L)","Leu(L)", "Ser(S)","Ser(S)","Ser(S)","Ser(S)","Tyr(Y)","Tyr(Y)", "Stop(*)","Stop(*)", "Cys(C)","Cys(C)","Stop(*)", "Trp(W)",
    "Leu(L)","Leu(L)","Leu(L)","Leu(L)","Pro(P)","Pro(P)","Pro(P)","Pro(P)","His(H)","His(H)","Gln(Q)","Gln(Q)","Arg(R)","Arg(R)","Arg(R)","Arg(R)",
    "Ile(I)","Ile(I)","Ile(I)","Met(M)","Thr(T)","Thr(T)","Thr(T)","Thr(T)","Asn(N)","Asn(N)","Lys(K)","Lys(K)","Ser(S)","Ser(S)","Arg(R)","Arg(R)",
    "Val(V)","Val(V)","Val(V)","Val(V)","Ala(A)","Ala(A)","Ala(A)","Ala(A)","Asp(D)","Asp(D)","Glu(E)","Glu(E)","Gly(G)","Gly(G)","Gly(G)","Gly(G)" };

// Variable declaration.
string DNA_string;
*string AA_string1[100];*
*string AA_string2[100];*
*string AA_string3[100];*

// User inputs DNA sequence.
cout << "Enter DNA sequence here: " << endl;
cin >> DNA_string;
cout << "\n";

// Preparing for sequence conversion.
int dnaLength = DNA_string.length();
int numberofCodons = dnaLength / 3;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int baseError;
string baseCorrect;
bool isCorrect = 0;

// Verifies if DNA sequence is inputted correctly.
while (isCorrect == 0)
{
    // Enters codons into the amino acid string array.
    j = 0;
    while (j <= numberofCodons)
    {
        for (i = 0; i <= dnaLength; i += 3)
        {
            AA_string1[j] = DNA_string.substr(i, 3);
            j += 1;
        }
    }
    // Displays the DNA sequence as sets of codons.
    for (i = 0; i <= numberofCodons; i++)
    {
        cout << AA_string1[i] << " ";
        // Indicates base position.
        if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0)
        {
            cout << ((i + 1) * 3) << " ";
        }
    }

  *UserVerify:*
  // Asks user to verify sequence.
    cout << "\nIs the following sequence correct?\n";
    cout << "Type 1 for yes and 0 for no: ";
    cin >> isCorrect;
    *if (isCorrect != 0 && isCorrect != 1)
    {
        cout << "Invalid Input: Please enter 1 or 0.";
        goto UserVerify;
    }*
    else if (isCorrect == 0)
    {
        cout << "\nPlease enter the base position you would like to change: 
                ";
        cin >> baseError;
        cout << "What should the base be changed to? If it should be 
                deleted, type 0: ";
        cin >> baseCorrect;
        if (baseCorrect == "0")
        {
            DNA_string = DNA_string.erase(baseError - 1, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            DNA_string = DNA_string.replace(baseError - 1, 1, baseCorrect);
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

*DNA_Conversion:*
// Converts DNA sequence into AA sequence over three ORFs.
// computeORF is a void function I made.
computeORF(AA_string1, 0, DNA_string, codons, aminoAcids);
computeORF(AA_string2, 1, DNA_string, codons, aminoAcids);
computeORF(AA_string3, 2, DNA_string, codons, aminoAcids);

system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow!  On SO, we have a very strict set of rules for on-topic questions, and it appears that this isn't on topic here.  For SO questions, you're expected to have something wrong with your code, provide an [MVCE], and do a bit of research.  It looks like this might be a great question for our sister site Code Review.SE.  I'll drop the mods a message to see if they can move it over.

Comment: Ok thank you, this is my first post so I wasn't aware. I can delete the post if need be, let me know.

Comment: You're very likely looking for [Code review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/); however, you'd need to read their ask page to see if it were on topic there. It's probably safe enough to simply delete this and copy+paste your question over.

Comment: `bool isCorrect = 0;` boolean values are `true` and `false`. Please use those. Also, avoid using `goto`. You should be able to find an alternative, like a loop in your case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is much too broad for Stack Overflow, which deals with more focused coding problems.  For advice on improving working code, consider [codereview.se] instead - but do read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there!.

Comment: Thank you all for the tips. As you guys recommended, I've transferred my question over to Code Review. However, I'm unable to delete this  post myself. For any moderators out there, feel free to close this post or delete it. I hope this off-topic post gets resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some issues with your program. First of all, indexes range from 0...n-1. If you have an array of length 10, the only indexes within that range are 0...9. Essentially all of your <= operators need to become < operators (since index 9 is the 10th allocated spot in an array).
Since you are iterating in steps of three, you will need to set your upper bound lower:

```
 for (i = 0; i <= dnaLength; i += 3)
```

becomes

```
for (i = 0; i < dnaLength - 3; i += 3)
```

Futhermore, you can use pointers for this assignment but that will only affect algorithm speed and will not allow dynamically allocated arrays. If you wish to change the length of a list in C++, I would recommend using *std::vector*.

To declare a pointer:

```
int *myPointer = 10;
```

Now myPointer is a memory address pointing to where the value 10 is stored.

```
&myPointer;
```

Will retrieve the value 10.

Additionally, regarding

```
(isCorrect != 0 && isCorrect != 1)
```

please check out this link: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/139177/

Comment: Thank you for posting your advice to my code! Very helpful!!

Comment: Would you mind upvoting my answer since you accepted it? :)